# GUI triggering actions in a separate process

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

I'm experiencing a problem with python-multiprocessing and Tkinter GUI.
I have two processes:

- main, running Tkinter GUI in a loop
- second process to do all other tasks

Here are the things I'm struggling with:

1. I want to trigger an action (f.eg. start a specific task in the second process) by clicking on a GUI button.
2. Then, when user clicks that button and the task in the second process starts, GUI changes the window to a new one (already know how to change windows). In the new one there is also a bunch of buttons, but I want them to be unclickable (or cause nothing when clicked) until the task in 2nd process is finished.

What is the best way to do this?

EDIT: Before I started to use multiprocessing, the code for my button and the triggered function looked like this:

```
button48g = tk.Button(self, text='48g', height = 10, width = 20, font=("Courier", 20), bg="WHITE", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(GUI.PageOne48g))
button48g.bind('<Button-1>', GUI.commands.leftClick)
```

where leftClick was a function, f.eg.

```
def leftClick(event):
    print('Left click!')
```

Now, the leftClick function is in the other process, called 'test'.

```
queueTestResults = multiprocessing.Queue()
test = multiprocessing.Process(name='test', target=testProcess, args=(queueTestResults,))
test.start()

gui = GUI.GuiApp()
gui.root.mainloop()

while queueTestResults.empty():
    pass

someResults = queueTestResults.get()
test.join()
```

Comment: please include some code ... then people will provide suggestions ... but i guess something like `threading.Thread(target=myTargetFn).start()`

Comment: I've added the code that might be helpful. Thanks for the suggestion, but itsn't the solution for multithreading instead of multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easier to accomplish with 2 Queues rather than 1 queue in my opinion

```
q_read,q_write = multiprocessing.Queue(),multiprocessing.Queue()

def slow_function():
    time.sleep(5)
    return "Done Sleeping"

def other_process_mainloop(q_write,q_read):
    # this process must get an inverted order
    while 1: # run forever
       while q_read.empty():
           time.sleep(0.1) # waiting for a message
       message = q_read.get()
       if message == "command":
           q_write.put(slow_function())
       else:
           q_write.put("Unknown Command")

# start our worker bee
P = multiprocessing.Process(name="worker",target=other_process_mainloop,
                                    # note inverted order
                            kwargs={q_write:q_read,q_read:q_write)
```

now make a helper function to send the command and wait for the response

```
def send_command(command_string,callback_fn):
    def check_for_response():
       if q_read.empty():
          return gui.after(200, check_for_response)
       callback_fn(q_read.get())

    q_write.put(command)
    gui.after(200,check_for_response)

# now you can just call this method when you want to send a command

def on_button_clicked(event):
    def on_result(result):
        print("Work is Done:",result)
        gui.lbl.configure(text="All Done!! {}".format(result))            

    gui.lbl.configure(text="Doing some work mate!")
    send_command("command",on_result)
```

Comment: Hi @Joran Beasley, i think this will also apply to my problem right now. Just want to which of the two functions is for GUI and which one for function once the button is clicked? Thank you